# Fail2ban vs OpenVPN Access Server

Tags: openvpn, regex, fail2ban

Example of a line in the logfile /var/log/openvpnas.log

```
2017-07-22 01:13:51+0200 [-] OVPN 4 OUT: "Fri Jul 21 23:13:51 2017 62.140.147.120:5414 SENT CONTROL [jeff]: 'AUTH_FAILED' (status=1)"
```

I want to use fail2ban to have the ip-adres 62.140.147.120 blocked when AUTH_FAILED is in that line, as is in the example line.
I have spend hours trying to accomplish this. Searching on Google. Experimenting with Regular Expressions. Still unable to make it work.

So far the most logical line in openvpn.conf seems to me:

```
failregex = ^ ... OVPN 4 OUT: \".* .* .* ..:..:.. .... <HOST>:.* SENT CONTROL .*: \'AUTH_FAILED\' $
```

But the command:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/openvpnas.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/openvpn.conf
```

keeps saying: 0 matched

Can anyone help me please?
What is the parameter for "failregex" that I have to enter in openvpn.conf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following failregex works for me:

`failregex = <HOST>:[0-9]+\sSENT\sCONTROL\s.*?AUTH_FAILED.*`

Testing with `fail2ban-regex` gives:

```
$ fail2ban-regex -v --print-all-matched openvpn.log "<HOST>:[0-9]+\sSENT\sCONTROL\s.*?AUTH_FAILED.*"

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : <HOST>:[0-9]+\sSENT\sCONTROL\s.*?AUTH_FAILED.*
Use         log file : openvpn.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 7 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [7] <HOST>:[0-9]+\sSENT\sCONTROL\s.*?AUTH_FAILED.*
|      31.77.70.2  Mon Mar 26 14:23:23 2018
|      31.77.70.2  Mon Mar 26 14:53:43 2018
|      31.77.70.2  Mon Mar 26 14:54:42 2018
|      31.77.70.2  Mon Mar 26 14:55:09 2018
|      31.77.70.2  Mon Mar 26 15:16:52 2018
|      31.77.70.2  Mon Mar 26 15:19:14 2018
|      31.77.70.2  Mon Mar 26 15:20:59 2018
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [5664] Year(?P<_sep>[-/.])Month(?P=_sep)Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:,Microseconds)?
|  [413] (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
|  [0] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])Month(?P=_sep)(?:Year|Year2) 24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)Year[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
|  [0] Month/Day/Year:24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Month-Day-Year 24hour:Minute:Second\.Microseconds
|  [0] TAI64N
|  [0] Epoch
|  [0] Year-Month-Day[T ]24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?:Zone offset)?
|  [0] ^24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] ^<Month/Day/Year2@24hour:Minute:Second>
|  [0] ^Year2MonthDay  ?24hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] MON Day, Year 12hour:Minute:Second AMPM
|  [0] ^MON-Day-Year2 24hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 6077 lines, 0 ignored, 7 matched, 6070 missed [processed in 3.84 sec]
|- Matched line(s):
|  2018-03-26 14:23:23+0100 [-] OVPN 4 OUT: "Mon Mar 26 14:23:23 2018 31.77.70.2:58835 SENT CONTROL [njarvis]: 'AUTH_FAILED' (status=1)"
|  2018-03-26 14:53:43+0100 [-] OVPN 4 OUT: "Mon Mar 26 14:53:43 2018 31.77.70.2:62055 SENT CONTROL [njarvis]: 'AUTH_FAILED' (status=1)"
|  2018-03-26 14:54:42+0100 [-] OVPN 4 OUT: "Mon Mar 26 14:54:42 2018 31.77.70.2:57913 SENT CONTROL [njarvis]: 'AUTH_FAILED' (status=1)"
|  2018-03-26 14:55:09+0100 [-] OVPN 4 OUT: "Mon Mar 26 14:55:09 2018 31.77.70.2:58704 SENT CONTROL [njarvis]: 'AUTH_FAILED' (status=1)"
|  2018-03-26 15:16:52+0100 [-] OVPN 4 OUT: "Mon Mar 26 15:16:52 2018 31.77.70.2:55038 SENT CONTROL [test]: 'AUTH_FAILED' (status=1)"
|  2018-03-26 15:19:14+0100 [-] OVPN 4 OUT: "Mon Mar 26 15:19:14 2018 31.77.70.2:50027 SENT CONTROL [test]: 'AUTH_FAILED,REVOKED: client certificate has been revoked' (status=1)"
|  2018-03-26 15:20:59+0100 [-] OVPN 4 OUT: "Mon Mar 26 15:20:59 2018 31.77.70.2:49564 SENT CONTROL [njarvis]: 'AUTH_FAILED' (status=1)"
`-
Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 6070 lines
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Neil.

Here are the contents of my filter.d file:

```
failregex = <HOST>:[0-9]+\sSENT\sCONTROL\s.*?AUTH_FAILED.*
ignoreregex = <HOST>:[0-9]+\sSENT\sCONTROL\s.*?AUTH_FAILED,SESSION
```